# Combinatorics problem: determining number of times the same combination occurs

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working on a problem where I have n indistinguishable items and I need to distribute them into m distinguishable "buckets." I know that the problem can be solved with stars-and-bars combinatorics and I've figured out how I'm supposed to determine the number of possible combinations, but I would also like to figure out how many times a particular combination occurs. For instance, if I'm dividing 3 similar red balls into 2 buckets labelled A and B, there would be (n+m-1)!/(n!(m-1)!) = (2+3-1)!/(2!(3-1)!) = 6 possible combinations. Is there an easy way to determine how many times a particular given combination can occur? For example, in the case where there are two balls in bucket A and 1 in bucket B, there are 3 possible ways this can occur: AAB, BAA, and ABA. I'm just not sure how to formulate this into an equation of some kind.

Sorry if this seems poorly-worded. I'm trying to solve this problem for a personal project involving running this programmatically, so I'm sorry if my combinatorics and math terminology is a little lacking.

Comment: You are looking for permutations of a multiset because you can have duplicate elements in a multiset.  Searching for that will give a lot of information.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for :)